# Cant find Moles after installation

Tags: unit-testing, moles, pex, pex-and-moles

I've installed Pex & moles and was trying to follow the tutorial

but couldnt add a new items --> moles to the test project for some reason

cant find the file type there

i've tried to reinstall it few times unsuccessfully...

what can i do ?

thanks

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tutorial says to add a new item? I thought that I read that on a old version of Moles.

Never mind. Actually, go to the References in your test project. Right-clik on the assembly you want to mole, you will have "Add Moles Assembly". For mscorlib, right-click directly on the References node and you will have "Add Moles Assembly for mscorlib".

Hope this help.

Comment: you're right! but how come the first moles tutorial in the main pex website is demonstrating the old method ?? where can i get the most up-to-dated tutorial ? thanks!

Comment: Hum, I'm a little surprised. I've download Moles from http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/downloads.aspx and I chose the Visual Studio Gallery version. This release of Moles comes with a manual, a tutorial up-to-dated, a Moles sample and several other things. However, I found that the tutorial and the examples was not enough. Use examples of Typemock or Justmock and try to do the same things with Moles is a good training.